# Why is my flutter app saves twice on firestore while my device is offline?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When my device is offline and tried to insert into firestore, it executes twice.

this my code in [adding document](https://gist.github.com/jrhml05/eb1a1df5c9a3a53514522601394b8dec) to firestore.

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firestore` doesn't support transactions neither `await` keyword for offline mode, just remove the runTransaction and await.

```
  Future<void> saveHouseHolder() async {
      CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance
            .collection('municipality')
            .document(global.mundocid)
            .collection('Barangay')
            .document(global.brgydocid)
            .collection('HouseHolderList');
         reference.add({
          'Name': name,
          'Gender': gender,
          'Age': age,
          'Spouse': spouse,
          'FullAddress': fullAdd,
          // 'Location':new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude),
          'ContactNumber': contactNo,
          'Origin': origin,
          'Language': language
        });

      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HouseHolder()));

        }
```

After your connection is restored, it will sync automatically.

Comment: oh, now I know.. Thanks for this! it really helped me..